# Check if open SMTP connection is closed/timed out

Tags: email, smtp, email-server

Is it possible to send some sort of ping to a SMTP server to check if the connection is still open and ready to send a mail

The connection is a keep alive and want to check if the connection is closed/timed out

Or is it possible to send a no operation command to keep the connection alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very quick look through the RFC shows [the SMTP NOOP command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.9).

> ```
>    This command does not affect any parameters or previously entered
>    commands.  It specifies no action other than that the receiver send a
>    "250 OK" reply.
>
>    This command has no effect on the reverse-path buffer, the forward-
>    path buffer, or the mail data buffer, and it may be issued at any
>    time.  If a parameter string is specified, servers SHOULD ignore it.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`NOOP` is good but `RSET`is better **before strarting new transaction** (sending new email) IMHO.
Anyway `sendmail` uses `RSET` to test SMTP connections retrieved from connection cache.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.5